# jQuery show/hide buttons

Tags: jquery, css

This is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/JedtY/1/

If you take a look at the result, you will see the first row, you will notice the buttons "Change" and "Delete".

Try to click on it, and another button will appear, "Add".

This row doesnt work as I would like to.

Now see the next row. This is not in basket. Click on the row, and an "Add" button will appear only. If you click again it will disappear. This works properly.

So my issue as is when it is in basket. I dont want it to show the buttons "Change" and "Delete" from the start, only when the row is highlighted (when you have clicked). And somehow the "Add" button activates and appears, which it shouldnt.

How can i fix this? I know my JS can seem to be dirty ( the append part, where all the html is ), but I have not found a better way to append data to the table.

Comment: 1. Don't use live, use delegate or .on(), 2. That jsfiddle doesn't work for me. It's saying, "updateBasket is not defined" and "delFromBasket is not defined". I noticed you are trying to put a form inside a table as well, that is invalid html.

Comment: I don't know about the <form> inside table, but not problems here using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If i undertood you correctly:

If you don't want the 'Add' button on the basket, why add the  on the JS? If you take it, it wont appear anymore, or just take the .hideme class you use to toggle the apearence.

The reason the 'Change' and 'Delete' appear right away is because you have the inline style set to display.

So, I assume this is what you are trying to achieve, yes?

http://jsfiddle.net/aHA92/

Hope it helps.